# sh: 1: del: not found

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, npm-install

I'm wondering if you can help me
Failed Heroku deploy. Been looking at other similar stack overflow posts and changing package.json file trying solutions that have worked for others with no luck. I don't think this is a port issue but it could be a package.json issue or something completely different. Any help, tips or advice is greatly appreciated!

Heroku Log:

```
 -----> Build
        Running build
        
        > honeyman-designs@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_a9c0d0bf
        > del dist && babel backend -d dist  && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build
   
 sh: 1: del: not found
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! syscall spawn
 npm ERR! file sh
 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
 npm ERR! honeyman-designs@1.0.0 build: `del dist && babel backend -d dist  && cd frontend && npm                     
 install && npm run build`
 npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the honeyman-designs@1.0.0 build script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.tyCCY/_logs/2020-12-31T15_09_59_938Z-debug.log
```

This is my package.json file:

```
 {
   "name": "honeyman-designs",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "dependencies": {
     "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
     "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
     "express": "^4.17.1",
     "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
     "mongoose": "^5.10.15",
     "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.2"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
     "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
     "@babel/node": "^7.12.1",
     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
     "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
   },
   "scripts": {
     "start": "nodemon --watch backend --exec babel-node backend/server.js",
     "build": "rd /s dist && babel backend -d dist  && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build",
     "heroku-postbuild-x": "npm run build && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build"
   },
   "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "git+https://github.com/codegreene93/HoneymanDesigns.git"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "bugs": {
     "url": "https://github.com/codegreene93/HoneymanDesigns/issues"
   },
   "homepage": "https://github.com/codegreene93/HoneymanDesigns#readme",
   "engines": {
     "node": "12.4.0",
     "npm": "6.14.10"
   }
 }
```

I have tried clearing cache and deleting and reinstalling **node_modules** and **package-lock.json**

I've updated the **node** and **npm** version

I'm using Windows 10 and I've also tried it like this:

`del dist && babel backend -d dist  && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build`

`rd /s dist && babel backend -d dist  && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build`

`rm -r dist && babel backend -d dist  && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build`

None of them run get the same sh:1 error

server.js file:

```
 app.listen(config.PORT, () => {
   console.log('Server started at http://localhost:5000');
 });
```

config.js

```
 PORT: process.env.PORT || 5001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rd` and `del` are *Windows* commands, but Heroku doesn't run Windows. You won't be able to use those commands on Heroku.

I suggest using a cross-platform alternative like [`rimraf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) insted of platform-specific commands so your scripts will run properly on your local development environment as well as your hosted environment.

Add it to your dependencies and then use something like

```
npx rimraf dist && babel backend -d dist  && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build
```